Why is there no SQL statement in MON$STATEMENTS.MON$SQL_TEXT for all active transactions in Firebird 2.5
I am trying to find the SQL statements for my active transactions and specifically for OAT.
I am running this query:
select MT.MON$TRANSACTION_ID,MT.MON$TIMESTAMP,MS.MON$STATEMENT_ID,MS.MON$SQL_TEXT
from MON$TRANSACTIONS MT
left join MON$STATEMENTS MS ON (MS.MON$TRANSACTION_ID=MT.MON$TRANSACTION_ID)
where MT.MON$STATE=1
order by MT.MON$TRANSACTION_ID

I get MON$SQL_TEXT only for some transactions and for OAT(MON$DATABASE.MON$OLDEST_ACTIVE) there are no records in MON$STATEMENTS
How to get MON$SQL_TEXT for OAT and other old active transactions?

MON$STATEMENTS shows a snapshot of the time you first accessed a monitoring table in your current transaction. Apparently there are no statements prepared in your active transactions at that exact time, or you haven't recently started a new transaction for executing that query, so you're looking at stale data.

Besides IIRC prepared statements are not linked to transactions at all, only currently running are.

The strange thing is that for example I have 2 active transactions that were started at the same time (2 hours ago) and for one of them there is MON$SQL_TEXT and for the other not, and they both are not currently running

Having an active transaction doesn't mean it is actively executing something. It just means it was started, but never committed or rolled back (or prepared for two-phase commit).

The problem is that you're querying for MON$STATE_ID with value 1. Statements are only in state 1 when they are actively executing or producing rows (to fulfill a fetch from the client).
Only in exceptional cases will this execution take a long time, so you're unlikely to see statements with that state (basically, only if you're "lucky", or if you have a statement that is very, very slow or waiting on a locked record). You will more likely see state 0 (idle), or state 2 (stalled). The 'stalled' state means a select or other result set producing statement was executed, and the server is waiting for the client to fetch rows from the cursor of the statement handle. The 'idle' state means that a statement handle exists (with or without a prepared statement), but is currently not executing nor waiting for the client to fetch rows (there is no open cursor, or all rows were fetched).
For all states you'll be able to see the MON$SQL_TEXT, though in state 0 it is possible you don't see any if 1) a statement was allocated, but nothing prepared yet, or 2) the statement was "unprepared" (i.e. the client asked the server to forget about the statement prepared on the statement handle).
Statements in state 0 are not associated with a transaction, so they have MON$TRANSACTION_ID value 0. If you don't see any statements for an active transaction, that means that the transaction currently has no active or stalled statements, which means it is not executing anything, or whatever is executing, was started with execute direct, which doesn't use a statement handle (though to be honest, I'm not sure if it might use a statement handle below the surface).

Hi Mark,
as far as I can see MON$TRANSACTIONS.MON$STATE is for Idle/Active and so I'm filtering on that as I'm only interested in the active transactions.
https://ib-aid.com/download/docs/firebird-language-reference-2.5/fblangref-appx05-transacs.html
What you described is true, but it is for MON$STATEMENTS.MON$STATE

@IvanIvanov Right, I had missed that in your query you're selecting active transactions, not active statements. However, the point still stands, if you have active transactions, but there are no active (or stalled) statements on that transactions, then that means that that transaction is not doing anything at the moment, except waiting for a commit or rollback.

@IvanIvanov And if you're actually asking how to see what transactions are doing when they're doing it, then you should look at the trace facility, not the monitoring tables.
